# Thumbnails not being created using ffmpeg in C#

Tags: c#, ffmpeg

I am trying to create thumbnail videos by overlaying an image on top of existing videos using `ffmpeg` in my C# application. However, despite the code running without errors and showing the "done" message, the thumbnail files are not being created.

Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
private void D()
{
    foreach (string file in listBox1.Items)
    {
        try
        {
            using (Process process = new Process())
            {
                process.StartInfo.FileName = "ffmpeg.exe";
                process.StartInfo.Arguments = $"-i \"{file}\" -i \"{image}\" -map 0 -map 1 -c copy -disposition:1 attached_pic \"{Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file)}_thumbnailed.mp4\"";
                process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                process.Start();
                process.WaitForExit();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"Error processing file: {file}\n\nError message: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
    MessageBox.Show("done");
}
```

I have verified that the file variable contains valid paths to existing video files, and the image variable points to an existing image file.

I also made sure that ffmpeg.exe is accessible from the application's working directory.

Despite these checks, the thumbnail files are not being created. Could anyone please help me identify what could be causing this issue? Is there anything I might be missing in the ffmpeg arguments or the way I'm using the Process class in C#?

Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated.